# Views on participation in the Chidon Hatanach

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tanach, responsa

In perusing [Rav Moshe Tzuriel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C)'s Otzros Hamussar (page 1125, [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=kjLAxKn2rMIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%91&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8ifDWg6viAhUknuAKHZjVD7kQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9F&f=false)), I noticed a section in which he writes strongly against participation in (and watching) the [Chidon Hatanach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bible_Contest), and also cites Rabbi Yechezkel Sarna as feeling the same way when a student in Chevron Yeshiva wanted to participate in it.

His reasoning is that it has turned Torah into a game, which is inappropriate. He also cites a passage from Sefer Chassidim which supports such an argument.

So, which other poskim have written about whether or not it is permitted to take part in/watch the Chidon Hatanach, and what was their response and reasoning?

Comment: Do you not agree/like his reasons? Or do you want more of the same reasons or new opposing ones?

Comment: I feel like I've been a part of Torah games every single Pesach Seder.

Comment: Surely some even consider this website a Torah game @doubleaa

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel "So, which poskim have written about whether or not it is permitted to take part in/watch the Chidon Hatanach, and what was their response and reasoning?" I would take any written responses from Rabbis on this topic, but I'm truthfully hoping for different reasons (whether pro or con) in addition to this one...

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Tzuriel (and the Sefer Chassidim) may indeed consider them inappropriate.

Comment: "מלקטים אסופות תיבות ע"פ דימוי חיצוני בלבד"??  What's wrong with that?  It's important data towards developing parallels and subtle differences between parts of Tanach.

Comment: לולי תורתך **שעשעי**

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=55555&st=&pgnum=589&hilite=

Answer (score 5):

I did a quick search and came up with the following two responsa:

Teshuvos Vehanhagos 1:548 (found [here](http://www.yoel-ab.com/forumIn.asp?top_id=16193&m_id=16157&title=%EE%F1%F4%F8%20%F0%F7%E5%E3%E5%FA)) forbids it, based on the fact that it is dangerous to interact and join together with the heretics that run it, and also that it supports those who interpret Tanach against traditional interpretations:

> שאלה:
>
> נשאלתי אם מותר להשתתף בחידון תנ"ך.
>
> נראה שהדבר אסור בהחלט.
>
> ראשית שהדבר עלול להזיק מאד לנער הנבחן שכן,המשתתפים בו וכן הבוחנים,מהם
> כופרים גמורים שלמדוהו ע"י מלמדים מעכו"ם ומפרשים אותו כפשוטו כספר
> מעשיות שהוא נגד קבלת חז"ל ר"ל.
>
> ועתה שילך עמם וישב איתם בצוותא ויתחבר עמהם יכול הוא מאד להזיק לאמונתו
> ויהדותו.
>
> ועוד,שבזה מחזקים את ידם לקיים התנ"ך שלא על פי חז"ל,וזהו מינות ממש.
>
> ובלימוד תנ"ך כפשוטו עלולים לגשם דברי נבואה ונביאים ולקלקל בזה כל
> השקפות וחינוך הנערים.
>
> והשתתפות כזאת ביחד של החפשיים או אפילו עכו"ם עם חרדים,מעולם לא הביא
> ברכה,ואנו עם לבדד ישכון.
>
> וכיון שדרך האדם להתפעל ולהיות נמשך מסביבתו וכמבואר ברמב"ם פרק ו
> דדעות,על כן חייבים להתרחק מחברה זאת,ואין להשתתף בחידון המתוכנן.

Surprisingly, a similar conclusion is drawn by Rabbi Dov Villner in a long responsum on Tzomet's website [here](http://www.zomet.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/tm-2-072veln.pdf) (originally printed in [Chemdas Tzvi 2:8](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21587&st=&pgnum=70&hilite=)). On page 9 he explains that it is prohibited to be in a Chidon together with non-Jews, and on page 12 he writes that it is prohibited to participate alongside those who reject Torah and Mitzvot, and says that it would even be prohibited to listen to the Chidon.

However, in Gilyonos Derech Hashem 001-070 page 267 (found on Otzar Hachochma), Rabbi Yitzchak Yosef mentions that his father used to listen to the Chidon Hatanach:

> [image]

Comment: If the word "heretics" is used in the responsum in Teshuvos Vehanhagos, you should put it in quotation marks and probably also include TV"H's justification for that designation.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst they don't talk about the Chidon HaTanach specifically, a Chinuch perspective about these sorts of competitions is provided by both Rav Shlomo Wolbe zt"l and the Slonimer Rebbe zt"l. Although the notion of "קנאת סופרים תרבה חכמה" – “Jealousy amongst scholars increases wisdom” ([Bava Basra 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.21a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) is generally regarded as permitted in order to motivate one’s students, the long-term fallout tends to be more destructive.

The Slonimer Rebbe in his Nesivei Chinuch (chapt 6, p.41) talks about the recent phenomenon of Mishna competitions and the like that are often surrounded in much pageantry and fanfare. These competitions are devised to get the child to learn reams of משניות off by heart. Although the end result makes for an impressive display of לימוד תורה, once the contest is over, the initial drive and enthusiasm fizzles out. Moreover, while there may be a winner, there are many more losers, which is not an easy thing for a child to experience, especially given the level of effort they expended in preparation for the competition.

He writes:

> לדעתי אם טוב הוא בשביל חינוך סטנדרטי בכדי לעורר קנאת ופרים אך לא טוב הוא בשביל חינוך יותר עילאי ומזיק יותר משמועיל
>
> “According to my opinion, whilst they are good for standard education in order to awaken a sense of (permitted) competitive spirit, nevertheless for the more elevated type of education we seek for our children, the effects of such competitions are more damaging than helpful”.

HaRav Shlomo Wolbe also adds that the כבוד, the honour gained by the winning participants, stays with them for a long time. The result ensures that they acquire a mind-set where they think they know everything, thereby losing the will to exert themselves, a vital factor needed in their spiritual growth. (Zeriya U'Binyan B'Chinuch - p.47)

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.

There is a man named [@Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex). He is known to possess large amounts of Jewish law and literature. He [teaches](http://gemara.org) a Talmud Daf Yomi class. He has also [participated](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=19230297#19230297) in the Chidon Tanach. I don't know if he would agree with others participating, but it seems reasonable to say that he would agree to it personally. Although he is not a known posek, it is likely he has a sort of qualifying semicha. His comments on the above link would demonstrate some of his opinions on the topic in writing, though not formally written.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Wieder

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9A

Comment: The point is you're not going to find responsa permitting this because they find it too obvious to write that studying Scripture is a good thing.